# How do I run a loop for a specific amount of time?

Tags: arduino-uno, time

I currently have a `for` loop that loops 300 times and then moves on.

Instead, I'd like that loop to run for a specific number of minutes, instead.

Here's the current loop, for reference.

```c
for(int i = 1; i<300; i++){
  if (kill() == true){ break; }

  strip.setPixelColor(1, strip.Color(random(100,255),random(100,255),random(100,255)));
  strip.show();

  tone(TONE, notes[random(0,3)]);
  delay(100);
}
```

Also, I have an RTC that's used elsewhere in the app, so real actual time is available for use if it makes sense to do that...though I'd love to know of a way to do it without an RTC module for future projects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example that will run for 5 minutes. Note that the loop will begin executing anytime before the time limit is up, including 1 msec before; it can't cut-off something happening at the 5-minute mark, meaning the timing precision will be limited to the duration of the code in the loop.

Update: My first suggestion had a bug related to the 50-some-odd days roll-over period of the millis() clock. This one is more robust:

```
uint32_t period = 5 * 60000L;       // 5 minutes

for( uint32_t tStart = millis();  (millis()-tStart) < period;  ){
   doStuff();
   moreStuff();
}
```

Comment: This is based on "5 minutes from the start of the Arduino" though, right?

Comment: No, it's based on the time of entry to the loop. The for-loop's first clause calculates the ending time, and the second clause compares the current time at the top of each loop to that time.

Comment: Just tested and works wonderfully. Thanks!

Comment: To your update, does `tQuit` need to be defined somewhere?

Comment: Acch! That what I get for coding on the fly! tQuit is no longer used (the bug was related to tQuit). That should say 'period'. (fixed). Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 3):

Using this example:

http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/ElapsedMillis

You could try something like:

```
#include <elapsedMillis.h>

elapsedMillis timeElapsed;
unsigned int interval = 60000; //one minute in ms

while(timeElapsed < interval){
    //do stuff
}
```

Depending on how accurate you want to be, you might want to opt for a similar method using the RTC.

Comment: Nice, *"These special variable types automatically increase as time elapses."*

Answer (score 2):

You can use a variable that is incremented each time you perform the loop, then you need only to change the loop from using a `for` to a `while`.

For example:

```
   int incremented_variable = 0;
   int incremented_value = 100;
   int max_value = 1000;  

   while(incremented_variable < max_value){
   if (kill() == true){ break; }

   strip.setPixelColor(1, strip.Color(random(100,255),random(100,255),random(100,255)));
   strip.show();

   tone(TONE, notes[random(0,3)]);

   delay(100);
   incremented_variable = incremented_variable + incremented_value;
   }
```

---

**EDIT:** I have just read your update on the question.

You can then use a while with a boolean flag that help you to end the loop or if you prefer, you can keep track of the time by calling the method: `millis()`.

Comment: But how does that equate to actual _time_? i.e. "This loop has been running for 5 minutes."

Comment: @Shpigford you can manage to control the time changing the `incremented_value` that now is set to 100 and the `max_value` that is set to 1000. As an advice run the script only once to see the time it takes to perform only one time than you set those value accordingly.